# Bootstrap trying to align logo to the left as well as center it

Tags: html, css, jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am Trying to align my logo to the left as well as center it on the navbar in that location. I have tried a few different things with no success and i am not able to move it any higher with a bottom padding for some reason. If anybody could offer some assistance it would be great. My logo is 800x800 so that is why i am sizing it down to 45px

Here is my Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand pull-left" href="#"><img id="logo" src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/static/images/nfl.gif"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Conferences <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Divisions</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#logo
{
float: left;
width:45px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.nav {
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `text-align` to center it:

```
.navbar-brand {
  text-align:center;
}
```

And add `height:100%` to get parent's height:

```
#logo {
 float: left;
 width:45px;
 height:100%;
}
```

And you want to fit your logo, then remove wrapper's padding:

```
.navbar-brand {
   text-align:center;
   padding:0 !important;
   margin:0;
}
```

```css
.navbar-brand {
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 !important;
  /*padding:0 !important;*/ /*uncomment to fit*/  
}
#logo
{
float: left;
width:45px;
height:100%;
}

.nav {
float:left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="https://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d7/jones1-800.jpg"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Conferences <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Divisions</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, worked perfect. used the second option as to not scrunch my logo. Thank you!